# Cohomology of sheaves : reference-request

Tags: reference-request

I need a good reference book where I can learn the cohomology of sheaves through the approach of Čech cohomology. The Hartshorne's book, for example, doesn't help me a lot because he choose the "derived functors approach".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number one  account is still in Serre's legendary *Faisceaux Algébriques Cohérents* (Chapitre I,§§3,4) of which you can find an English translation [here](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~pta/fac/fac.pdf).
[Grothendieck had not yet introduced his more abstract version of sheaf cohomology at the time but was soon to do so]

You can also look at sections 7.8 and 7.9 of [Taylor's textbook](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Several_Complex_Variables_With_Connectio.html?id=i8lUNpZ379MC&redir_esc=y) .

Another excellent textbook is [that by Fritsche-Grauert](http://books.google.fr/books/about/From_Holomorphic_Functions_to_Complex_Ma.html?id=jSeRz36zXIMC&redir_esc=y), where you will find in Chapter IV,§3 not only Čech cohomology for sheaves but also its relation to classical singular cohomology.

A more technical account for algebraic geometers is in Chapter VII of [Mumford-Oda's notes](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~chai/624_08/mumford-oda_chap7-8.pdf) .
[I think these notes are a reworking of a draft for a mythical book projected by Mumford, which was to revise and extend his famous red book.
 The book never materialized because of Mumford's scientific reconversion to theoretical computer science. The online notes are available by courtesy of  [Professor Chai](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~chai/624_08/math624_08.html)]

Answer (score 2):

The most "down-to-earth" book I know that covers this topic is Rick Miranda's *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*. It goes slow, has a lot of examples, and has minimal prerequisites.

You might also try Bott and Tu's *Differential forms in Algebraic Topology* or Bredon's *Sheaf Theory* for different perspectives.

Comment: I only know the Bredon. He defines sheaf cohomology in terms of the Godement resolution and then devotes quite some time on disccusing the links between Alexander-Spanier, De Rham, Singular and Cech cohomology and sheaf cohomology.